# Why does recv() with MSG_PEEK block?

Tags: c, network-programming

Only once, when a new connection is created, I want to peek into the stream to determine whether or not the connection is an SSL connection. To do this I use recv() with the MSG_PEEK flag. The problem is that for connections which are not SSL connections and dont have any initial incoming data the recv blocks for a few seconds. How do I fix that?

Comment: Use non-blocking file descriptors?

Comment: @KerrekSB i dont want to have to rewrite the entire network handling portion of my code simply to make this work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want the call to block, you can supply the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag as well (not POSIX, but widely implemented) - but how would you tell the difference between an SSL connection where the initial data just hasn't arrived yet and a non-SSL connection?

It seems that to do this reliably you will need to wait for the first portion of data to arrive anyway.